# Anyway to change the property of a existing animation to another type?

Tags: animation, unity

The title pretty much says it all. Take this rather simple animation 
[image]
I would like to reuse this same animation in a UI element but  for that I have to animate the Image component and not the sprite. Is there a way to copy over the keys or edit the animation somehow so that the property is a Image.sprite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is how I did it.

1. Set asset serialization mode to force text
2. Create a empty animation clip containing the Image.sprite property.
3. Open up the new and old animations and copy everything bellow
   `-curve:` and `pptrCurveMapping:` from the old one to the new one.
4. Enjoy your new animation that works with UI images.